# Добавление записи в БД через форму

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, post, форматирование

Вношу данные в БД через форму  в отдельном файле и методом POST отправляю их. Но почему-то данные в бд не появляются,что неправильно делаю? Помогите пожалуйста

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Добавление клиента</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="add.php">

клиент<br/>
<input type="text" name="klient" /><br/>

ОП_форма <br/>
<textarea name="op_firma" ></textarea> <br/> <!-- cols="10" rows="10" -->

Наимен <br/>
<input type="text" name="naimen"  /><br/><br/>
отрасль <br/>
<input type="text" name="otrasl"  /><br/><br/>
telefon <br/>
<input type="text" name="telefon"  /><br/><br/>
email <br/>
<input type="text" name="email"  /><br/><br/>
ОП фирмы <br/>
<input type="text" name="kont_lico"  /><br/><br/>
ОП фирмы <br/>
<input type="text" name="dolznost"  /><br/><br/>

<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date ('Y-m-d');?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo date ('H-i-s');?>" />

<input type="submit" name="add" value="Добавить" />
</form>
<?php
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","reklama","reklama") ;
$db=mysql_select_db(reklama);
mysql_set_charset("utf8");

if (!$connection || !$db)
{
exit(mysql_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['add']))  
{
$klient = strip_tags(trim($_POST ['klient']))  ;
$op_firma=strip_tags(trim($_POST ['op_firma']))  ;
$naimen=strip_tags(trim($_POST ['naimen']))  ;
$otrasl=strip_tags(trim($_POST ['otrasl']))  ;
$telefon=strip_tags(trim($_POST['telefon']))  ;
$email=strip_tags(trim($_POST ['email']))  ;
$kont_lico=strip_tags(trim($_POST ['kont_lico']))  ;
$dolznost=strip_tags(trim($_POST ['dolznost']))  ;
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];

mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO klienti(klient,op_firma,naimen,otrasl,telefon,email,kont_lico,dolznost,date,time)
    VALUES ('$klient', '$op_firma', '$naimen', '$otrasl', '$telefon', '$email', '$kont_lico',$dolznost', '$date', '$time')  
           ");
mysql_close();
echo "Новость успешно добавлена";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Добавление клиента</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="add.php">

клиент<br/>
<input type="text" name="klient" /><br/>

ОП_форма <br/>
<textarea name="op_firma" ></textarea> <br/> <!-- cols="10" rows="10" -->

Наимен <br/>
<input type="text" name="naimen"  /><br/><br/>
отрасль <br/>
<input type="text" name="otrasl"  /><br/><br/>
telefon <br/>
<input type="text" name="telefon"  /><br/><br/>
email <br/>
<input type="text" name="email"  /><br/><br/>
ОП фирмы <br/>
<input type="text" name="kont_lico"  /><br/><br/>
ОП фирмы <br/>
<input type="text" name="dolznost"  /><br/><br/>

<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date ('Y-m-d');?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo date ('H-i-s');?>" />

<input type="submit" name="add" value="Добавить" />
</form>
<?php
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","reklama","reklama") ;
$db=mysql_select_db('reklama');
mysql_set_charset("utf8");

if (!$connection || !$db)
{
exit(mysql_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['add']))  
{
$klient = strip_tags(trim($_POST['klient']))  ;
$op_firma=strip_tags(trim($_POST['op_firma']))  ;
$naimen=strip_tags(trim($_POST['naimen']))  ;
$otrasl=strip_tags(trim($_POST['otrasl']))  ;
$telefon=strip_tags(trim($_POST['telefon']))  ;
$email=strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']))  ;
$kont_lico=strip_tags(trim($_POST['kont_lico']))  ;
$dolznost=strip_tags(trim($_POST['dolznost']))  ;
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];

mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO klienti(klient,op_firma,naimen,otrasl,telefon,email,kont_lico,dolznost,date,time)
    VALUES ('{$klient}', '{$op_firma}', '{$naimen}', '{$otrasl}', '{$telefon}', '{$email}', '{$kont_lico}','{$dolznost}', '{$date}', '{$time}')  
           ");
mysql_close();
echo "Новость успешно добавлена";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Всё равно в бд не появлятся запись

Answer (score 0):

Выполнил свой запрос в  phpmyadmin и увидел ошибку, она оказалась в моей невнимательности,поле в бд было 'op_forma' , а я написал 'op_firma'.